# MongoMapper save not working

Tags: ruby, mongodb, sinatra, mongomapper

No idea why this is not working. It's the first time I am working with Mongo, but from all the docs I have read, this should work? Anyone have any idea what I am missing?

```
require 'rubygems'                                                                                                                                                                                      
require 'sinatra/base' 
require 'mongo_mapper'                                                                                                                                                                                  

  mongo_server = '127.0.0.1'                                                                                                                                                       
  mongo_database = 'inone'                                                                                                                                                         

  MongoMapper.connection = Mongo::Connection.new(mongo_server)                                                                                                                                            
  MongoMapper.database = mongo_database                                                                                                                                                                   

  # DB model                                                                                                                                                                                              
  class URLstore                                                                                                                                                                                          
    include MongoMapper::Document                                                                                                                                                                         

    key :url_key, String                                                                                                                                                                                  
    key :url, String                                                                                                                                                                                      
  end                      

class URLnip < Sinatra::Base                                                                                                                                                                            
   get '/testmongo' do         
    nipurl = URLstore.new(:url_key => "abc", :url => "www.google.com")                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
    nipurl.save  
  end
end
```

Opening the Mongo terminal I can see the DB get's created

```
> show dbs
inone   0.203125GB
```

but doing this brings back no results at all

```
> db.inone.find()
>
```

or

```
> db.inone.find({url : 'www.google.com'})
>
```

same thing nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shouldn't that be `db.urlstore.find()`? Or however `MongoMapper` changes the case. What does `show collections` in a Mongo shell say after you select the right database?

Comment: > use inone
      switched to db inone
    > show collections
      system.indexes
      ur_lstores

Comment: Have you tried `db.ur_lstores.find()`? You should maybe change your class name, it doesn't seem to go well with `MongoMapper`'s naming scheme. Make sure you are in the right db btw, so `use inone` before you try the aforementioned command.